# Reading exactly one row from Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, refactoring

I want to refactor some C# modules that read data from SQL Server 2008 via Linq-to-SQL. These stored procedures fetch at most one row, because I am submitting the full PK as parameters. Apparently Linq-to-SQL is not aware that at most one row can be returned. As a result, the following code runs to get one value or throw an exception:

```
    var results = context.MyProcName(myParameter);
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        return result.THeColumnINeed;
    }
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Value not found for parameter {0}", myParameter));
```

This code get the job done, but it kinda looks ugly. How can I do it better?

Comment: "kinda looks ugly" is an understatement. My friend, as per Marc's answer, join the world of [LINQ query operator methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx). :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return context.MyProcName(myParameter).Single().THeColumnINeed;
```

Comment: I would recommend using `.SingleOrDefault()` instead of just `.Single()` to avoid getting an exception if there was no record to be found.

Comment: @Simon an exception when there is no record is ***exactly*** what the question asks for...

Comment: @Simon Bondo Since `SingleOrDefault()` will almost certainly return `null` if no record was found, the statement above will throw a `NullReferenceException`, which obscures the real issue. OP should prefer `Single()` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`return context.MyProcName(myParameter).First();`

Comment: Single is better for his use case as it throws an exception if more than one record exists. Since his SPR is returning data based on a PK, it would be nice to know that he got multiple records back instead of whatever one First() returned. It makes tracking down the bug (of why he's getting multiple records from the SPR) a lot easier.